# Delayed/Lazy resolve

Tags: castle-windsor, lazy-evaluation, resolve

Given the following code:

```cs
public interface IMyContext
{
    string subtype { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : IMyContext
{
    public string subtype { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyExporter
{
    string Export();
}

public class MyExporterXML : IMyExporter
{
    public string Export()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class MyExporterJson : IMyExporter
{
    public string Export()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class MyExporterFactory
{
    private IMyContext context;
    public MyExporterFactory(IMyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IMyExporter Create()
    {
        switch (context.subtype)
        {
            case "JSON" :
                    return new MyExporterJson();
            default:
                    return new MyExporterXML();
        }
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private IMyContext context;
    private IMyExporter exporter;
    public MyService(IMyContext context, IMyExporter exporter)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.exporter = exporter;
    }

    public string Extractdata()
    {
        return exporter.Export();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>());
        container.Register(Component.For<MyExporterFactory>());
        container.Register(Component.For<MyService>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyExporter>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<MyExporterFactory>().Create()));
        var context = container.Resolve<IMyContext>();
        var service = container.Resolve<MyService>();

        context.subtype = "JSON";

        service.Extractdata();

    }
}
```

Is there a way to have the injected exporter in the MyService resolved at the time where it's actually used ?? Ie. when running the above code, the exporter resolved is the MyExporterXML, but I really want's it to be the MyExporterJson because of the context.subtype = "JSON" setting. However the exporter is resolved before the subtype is set...

I know Castle::Windsor has something called delegate-based factories, but I simply can't figure out how to use it....

Any help would be greatly appreciated, TIA

Søren

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of TypeFactoryFacility and a custom ITypedFactoryComponentSelector.  Here's something that should work in your case.

First, create an interface for the factory:

```
public interface IMyExporterFactory
{
    IMyExporter GetExporter(IMyContext context);
}
```

Next, use a customized factory component selector that will use the context's subtype to determine the component name (and change the registration to name your exporters):

```
public class ExporterComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (method.Name == "GetExporter")
        {
            var context = (IMyContext) arguments[0];
            return context.subtype;
        }

        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
}
```

Here's an update to your Windsor registration code that includes the TypedFactoryFacility and the custom selector (and it names your exporters based on their subtype):

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyExporterFactory>().AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith(new ExporterComponentSelector())),
    Component.For<IMyExporter>().ImplementedBy<MyExporterJson>().Named("json"),
    Component.For<IMyExporter>().ImplementedBy<MyExporterXML>().Named("xml"),
    Component.For<IMyContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>(),
    Component.For<MyService>()
    );
```

Now your service simply receives an IMyExporterFactory and uses that to resolve the exporter:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IMyContext context;
    private readonly IMyExporterFactory exporterFactory;

    public MyService(IMyContext context, IMyExporterFactory exporterFactory)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.exporterFactory = exporterFactory;
    }

    public string Extractdata()
    {
        var exporter = exporterFactory.GetExporter(context);
        return exporter.Export();
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to ensure that if the components are registered with lowercase names ("xml", "json") that your code always uses lowercase names (or use context.subtype.ToLower() in your ExporterComponentSelector).

Comment: Yeah, but what I really wanted was to have the correct Exporter injected into the MyService....

Comment: Why does it have to be injected? Why can't you use a factory?  To be honest, using the factory is a little more robust in this case.  If the "MyService" class changed the context.subtype (for some reason) before your call to Extractdata, you'd still have the exporter from the ctor. By resolving using the factory, you're assured that you'll always use the correct exporter based on the context's subtype at the time Extractdata() is called.

Comment: It doesn't have to be injected, it would just be very nice to hide this delayed dependency away, since the developer writing the service has no knowledge about choosine either the one or the oter exporter, he just need to know that there is one and that it can be used. Just thought there was a way to control what gets resolved based on a delayed depency.

Comment: +1 This problem is nearly exactly my problem, and the solution is so simple it was staring me in the face!  Thanks.